# error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c++, condiciones

Estoy intentado realizar una condición con una variable de tipo char, y me aparece el siguiente error:

> error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer
>   [-fpermissive]."}while(empleado[numEmpleados].sexo != 'h');"

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
struct datosEmpleado{
        int id;
        string nombre;
        int edad;
        char sexo[1];
        string telefono;
        int montoT;
};
do{
    cout<<"Sexo (h/m): ";
    cin>>empleado[numEmpleados].sexo;
    if(empleado[numEmpleados].sexo != 'h'){
       cout<<"No escribiste una opción válida\n";
    }
}while(empleado[numEmpleados].sexo != 'h');
```

El error aparece tanto en el **if** como en el **while**.
Tengo entendido que es porque el `char` no puede compararse con un entero, pero no veo donde estoy haciendo este error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En C y C++, un tipo formación (`X[]`) **no puede tratarse directamente**. El lenguaje no tiene el concepto de `formación`, y cualquier intento de tratar con una variable o expresión de ese tipo, *decae* automaticamente a un tipo puntero compatible:

Si pudieraramos ver directamente el tipo de una variable en C/C++, sería algo como esto:

```
int i;
typeof( i ) => 'int'

int *pi;
typeof( pi ) => 'int *';

char a[1];
typeof( a ) => 'char *'
typeof( a[1] ) => 'char'
```

Si lo piensas bien, verás que para definir una *formación* se necesitan 2 datos: inicio y tamaño. Y el lenguaje, por si mismo, no proporciona esto. Los accesos a las formaciones se permiten **sin comprobar el tamaño**. Simplemente, el lenguaje no tiene ese concepto.

La solución, en tu caso, es simple: **no** necesitas una formación, te basta con un `char` simple. Cambia tu `struct` a:

```
struct datosEmpleado {
  int id;
  string nombre;
  int edad;
  char sexo;
  string telefono;
  int montoT;
};
```